# Conditional pageBlockTable coloumns using inline IF statement

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, pageblocktable

I am trying to use highlighted columns in a `pageBlockTable` according to a specific value.

In this code I am trying to give this column a red background, but I keep getting `syntax error`

Here is my code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list}" var="d">
  <apex:column style="{!IF({!d.manager== 'user1'},'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" >
    <apex:facet name="header">
      <apex:commandLink value="Name"/>
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!d.Name__c}"></apex:outputText>
  </apex:column>
.
.
.
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have  `{...}` rather than `(...)` surrounding your IF condition, switch those and it should (hopefully) work.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list}" var="d">
    <apex:column style="{!IF(!(d.manager == 'user1)','background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" >
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:commandLink value="Name"/>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!d.Name__c}"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
.
.
.
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: it looks like you still have two opening {'s in there. Theres another before !d

Comment: @PhilB Good spot, fixed my answer.

Comment: Yes it was about brackets, thanks guys @alex-tennant and PhilB.

Comment: @HasanKhatib Don't forget to accept my answer if it's resolved your query to help out future users of the StackExchange.

Comment: The negation operator is buggy in certain circumstances of rendering / IF functions within visualforce.  Instead of using !, you can simply swap the true / false conditions.  e.g. style="{!IF(d.manager == 'user1','','background:rgb(243, 171, 171);')}